# Javascript: changing relative path will no open url right

Tags: javascript, html

basically, I try to mimic the following html behavior:

```
<button onClick="parent.location='page_confirm.html'" type="submit">Continue</button>
```

In JS:

```
window.location.pathname = '/page_confirm.html'
```

But this will just remove the base path and simply go to "/page_confirm.html". Which, without the path, ofc doesnt exist.

How can I mimic the exact call from the html in JS?

Thanks

Comment: You should be setting `window.location.href` not pathname. So `window.location.href = 'page_confirm.html';` .

Comment: this will still do the same and remove the base path (locally hosted atm)

Comment: Well you include a `/` in one and not in the other.... The urls are different.

Comment: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/56840/what-is-the-purpose-of-leading-slash-in-html-urls

Comment: omg, that was embarresing. tank you